ggplot2: rectangular background behind axis text in circular bar plot
Goal
Replicating this circular bar plot:

Data
data <- data.frame(
  labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
  values = c(88, 61, 56, 77, 83, 63, 42, 60)
) %>%
  mutate(
    bar_color = case_when(
      values < 62 ~ "#ff7d48",
      values < 85 ~ "#76c5d0",
      values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84",
    )
  )

My Code
ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    aes(
      x = labels,
      y = values,
      fill = bar_color
    ),
    size = 1,
    color = "gray20",
    width = 1,
    alpha = 0.9
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = "grey30"
    ),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = alpha("grey70", 0.5)
    ),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x.top = element_line(
      color = "grey20"
    ),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
  )

Initial result based on my code:

Need help on:

The top line of x axis need to be grey30. The axis.line.x.top seems has no effect. Even after I remove coord_polar() just to test, it also didnt show any grey line.
The I want the x axis text to have rectangular background. I've tried two attemps for this:


Use axis.text.x = element_textbox(color = "black",fill = "white"), it returns error: Error: The function textbox_grob() is not vectorized.
Use geom_label(aes(x = labels,y = 100,label = labels); the label just too centered regardless how I edit the y argument. for example y = 150 still makes the label too centered but it expand the y axis; I intentionally let x axis text to be there just to compare the position of geom_label that i expected



How to make panel.grid.major.x on top of panel.grid.major.y. In return, now i just set the color of the second to alpha("grey70", 0.5)


Edit:
You can 'automate' some of the plotting (e.g. calculate how many groups you have before plotting), but working out the breaks is complicated will require tweaking depending on your dataset (e.g. +1 or -1 accordingly):
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(
  labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
  values = c(88, 61, 56, 77, 83, 63, 42, 60)
) %>%
  mutate(
    bar_color = case_when(
      values < 62 ~ "#f2452e",
      values < 85 ~ "#76c5d0",
      values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84",
    )
  )

n <- length(unique(data$labels))
max_val <- max(data$values)
breaks_ext <- extended_breaks()(data$values)

ggplot(data, aes(x = labels, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = bar_color),
           stat = "identity", linewidth = 1,
           color = "gray20", width = 1,
           alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_polar(start = -(pi / n)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = c(rep(alpha("grey80", 0.5),
                    ifelse(max(breaks_ext) > max_val,
                           length(breaks_ext) - 2)), # change this manually to suit
                "transparent")
    ),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max_val + (max_val * 0.1),
             color = "grey90", linewidth = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5:(n + 0.5), y = 0,
                   yend = max_val + (max_val * 0.075)),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, color = alpha("grey20", 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max_val + (max_val * 0.07),
             color = "grey20", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels, y = max_val + (max_val * 0.09)),
             fill = "white", size = 6)


With 'new' data:

####
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(
  labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H", "I", "J"),
  values = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(
    bar_color = case_when(
      values < 62 ~ "#f2452e",
      values < 85 ~ "#76c5d0",
      values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84",
    )
  )

n <- length(unique(data$labels))
max_val <- max(data$values)
breaks_ext <- extended_breaks()(data$values)

ggplot(data, aes(x = labels, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = bar_color),
           stat = "identity", linewidth = 1,
           color = "gray20", width = 1,
           alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_polar(start = -(pi / n)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = c(rep(alpha("grey80", 0.5),
                    ifelse(max(breaks_ext) > max_val,
                           length(breaks_ext))), # change this manually to suit
                "transparent")
    ),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max_val + (max_val * 0.1),
             color = "grey90", linewidth = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5:(n + 0.5), y = 0,
                   yend = max_val + (max_val * 0.075)),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, color = alpha("grey20", 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max_val + (max_val * 0.07),
             color = "grey20", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels, y = max_val + (max_val * 0.09)),
             fill = "white", size = 6)


Created on 2024-12-16 with reprex v2.1.0

Original answer:
Here is one potential approach:
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
  values = c(88, 61, 56, 77, 83, 63, 42, 60)
) %>%
  mutate(
    bar_color = case_when(
      values < 62 ~ "#f2452e",
      values < 85 ~ "#76c5d0",
      values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84",
    )
  )

ggplot(data, aes(x = labels, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = bar_color),
           stat = "identity", size = 1,
           color = "gray20", width = 1,
           alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_polar(start = -(pi / 8)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = c("transparent", alpha("grey80", 0.5))
    ),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 96.5,
             color = "grey90", size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 95, 5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5:8.5, y = 0, yend = 95),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, color = alpha("grey20", 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 94,
             color = "grey20", size = 1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels, y = 96), fill = "white", size = 6)
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


Created on 2024-12-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks for your answer @jared_mamrot. This is in fact beyond my expectation, you managed to do something outside the score that I plan to do it later on. Now I'll study your approach and reverse engineer that!

I find difficulties when reverse engineer you code. Mainly due to the value of breaks in scale_y_continuous(), yintercept in geom_hline(), yend in geom_segment(), and y in geom_label(). I found this all hardcoded. It become challange when data$values change above 95 (max is 100). Do you mind elaborate how you get this or make the code scalable? Thanks

To address your issues: for a grey top line in the polar plot, use geom_hline(yintercept = max(data$values), color = "grey30", size = 0.8) since axis.line.x.top doesn’t apply in coord_polar(). To add rectangular backgrounds to axis text, use element_textbox from the ggtext package with theme(axis.text.x = element_textbox(color = "black", fill = "white", box.color = "grey30")), or alternatively, use geom_label to manually position labels outside the bars. To overlay panel.grid.major.x on panel.grid.major.y, use geom_segment to manually add X grid lines on top with aes(x = labels, xend = labels, y = 0, yend = max(data$values)). This ensures full customization of your circular bar plot.

Thanks for the response @Lokesh_thakur; in principal, I've tried all your suggestion before, it indeed getting closer to the reference plot (some return error), but still not serve my aim and the problem remains, as precisely explained by @jared_mamrot
